# spring batch master slave multiple job parallel

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch application with the master-slave pattern.
Now, this batch job runs once at a time for one client/customer.

I want to re-design the spring batch job with the master-slave pattern in such a way that it supports parallel jobs for the respective clients/customers.

Please provide me a path forward.

Comment: How are job instances defined? ie What are the identifying job parameters for your job? Depending on that, you might not need to re-design the entire job, but only modify how input parameters are passed so that you can can run multiple instances of the same job in parallel.

Comment: Also, please avoid using the "master/slave" terminology. We (the Spring team) have replaced the usage of such terms with "manager/worker" instead and we encourage our community to join the effort and avoid such terms as well. Thank you.